# How do 'area', 'region', and 'territory' differ?

Tags: differences, word-usage, dictionaries

When you consider separation for easy identification and management in sales, what would be the best explanations for *area*, *region*, and *territory*?

Comment: Can you expand a bit on the context? It's not very clear.

Comment: I'm in sales, and individual reps (sales people) have "territories" which they are responsible for developing (i.e. closing sales within) and which are exclusive (i.e. off limits to other individual reps), and the collection of all individual rep's territories reporting to a single manager is that manager's "region". I haven't heard the term "area" used at all. In re "easy identification", squabbles over territories are common, just like among gangs and sparrows. Don't expect them to go away.

Comment: This question too domain-specific to answer here.  The three words may be able to be used interchangeably in some contexts, but the conventions of the specific context you are talking about (sales) are the most important thing.  This isn't a forum about sales

Comment: @Max Williams I need only good explanation of the difference I mean hierarchy according to English Language explanation.

Comment: There isn't really a hierarchy.  Territory has an extra meaning that it "belongs to somebody", but there's no "size ordering".

Comment: Please give what you've found already about these three. Otherwise this question may be closed due to lack of diligence on your part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have usually encountered these terms in connection with sales, "territory" is generally the smallest division, lowest in the hierarchy.  "Region" is next larger/higher, consists of multiple territories.  "Area" is at the top, and contains multiple regions.  See, for example:

https://www.espatial.com/manage-market-effectively-territory-mapping-software

"Territory" is the provence of an individual salesperson; a "region" of multiple territories/salespeople would be supervised by a manager.  "Area" is more of a corporate planning term, but might also be specifically assigned to a higher level manager.

As someone noted earlier, however, it is not uncommon for these words (and particularly "area" and "region") to be used interchangeably in some contexts.

Comment: This also isn't strictly true. Territory can refer to entire states. Area can also refer to "the area around my desk." The only difference is that they have different meanings that can refer to the things you have referenced.

Comment: @AHuman:  While the words can indeed have different meanings in different contexts, in a *sales* context they generally means what I said.  No one in a general meeting of sales management teams is going to think "the area around my desk" when division of resources per area is brought up for discussion.

As to territory referring to entire states, yes, that's possible.  It's also possible that a whole state may constitute a single salesman's territory, with his state being a member of the "Northeast Region", and that region being part of the area east of the Mississippi.  See example link.

Comment: Oh. I didn't read the question fully...

Comment: Thanks everybody. As I realized  **Territory** is smaller than **Region** according to place where we are using. Anyhow can we use Territory is equal to Region ? Territory is use or not generally in sales field  ?